# address of static variable are different from `this` only when source file exists - but problem disappears if all code is in one header

Tags: c++, header-files

I tested this in wandbox.org

Foo.h ::-

```
struct Foo {
    Foo();
    void dummy(){}
};
static Foo foo;
```

Foo.cpp ::-

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>
Foo::Foo()  {
    std::cout<<&foo<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<this<<std::endl;
};
```

main.cpp ::-

```
#include "a.h"
int main(){
    foo.dummy();
}
```

Result ::-

```
0x7f333ff1077e
0x7f333ff1077e
0x7f333ff1077e
0x7f333ff1077c
```

1. Why 2 thread local variables are created?    (not 1? / is it actually 1?)
2. Why the address of `&foo` and `this` are not the same?

If I pack all of code into 1 header, the result will be as expected.  ( https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9184eae09b0bffd )

```
0x7f385b59973f
0x7f385b59973f
```

Comment: Why are you using `thread_local` or `static`?

Comment: @JaMiT :: omg, you are right, will remove it

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt  :: because I want 1 instance of `Foo` for each thread.

Comment: @JaMiT  :: Certainly.  Thank a lot!  I will accept the duplicate.

Comment: ...and you think applying those keywords will achieve that? Make sure you actually study their meaning!

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt  :: My bad.  Thank for the advice. You all are so wholesome.

Comment: BTW: cppreference.com, bookmark that. It's not an introductory text or a tutorial, but if you need a reference, that's the place to go.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt :: This site is very useful indeed.  Do you happen to know a site that is a bit less formal / more beginner friendly?  It doesn't need to 100% precisely correct like cppreference.  Thank.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. Apart from that, https://accu.org/ has a book review section.